# How to plot the "is proportional to" symbol in R

Tags: r, expression, symbols

Does anybody know if it is possible to insert a "is proportional to" symbol in an expression string in R?

Comment: Hi! Before you post a question on SO, you should at least attempt to solve you problem by yourself. That said, perhaps [this](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) will help? Also, take a look at [on-topic SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @RobertRossmann I agree but this is one of those cases that isn't the easiest to find in the R documentation without knowing where to look.  Also I already had that in my answer.

Comment: @Dason I know absolutely nothing about R and found the link in my comment by copy-pasting part of the question into Google. Third link contained the answer (which your answer confirms is correct).

Comment: @Dason I did, the problem was my implementation using expression. I had a few strings before and after the x %prop% y part in question, which i had some problem fixing. Thank you for your help though! My solution is below

expression("BLAH" ~ y %prop% x ~ "BLAH")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
expression(x %~~% y)
expression(x %prop% y)
```

An example

```
# Approximately equal
x <- 1:10
y <- x + rnorm(10,0,.01)
plot(x, y, main = expression(y %~~% x))

# Proportional to...
x <- 1:10
y <- 3*x
plot(x, y, main = expression(y %prop% x))
```

Take a look at `?plotmath` for documentation and more examples.